# The math symbols cannot be correctly displayed in titles and comments (in Stack Exchange Android App)

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment, titles, android-app

The question is as the title. More specifically, as a frequent mathematics stack exchange user, when I used my cell phone to check the stack exchange app, I feel very disappointed that the math expressions enclosed in math environment, when appeared in titles and comments, are not complied and displayed in a verbatim way. Due to this issue, I would rather to use the web page directly than using the stack exchange android app. This looks a quite serious bug, is it possible to fix it so that we can have a substantially better users interface?

Comment: I see, but there didn't explain the title issue. My actually question is, why the developer did't render the MathJax in titles and comments, is it because it is technically difficult or other reasons? It just doesn't make sense as the current appearence of titles and comments are terrible. Also, I think the "tap to render the MathJax" is a unsatisfactory solution.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221930 and  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256480 no point in rehashing this over and over.