# Mathjax symbols do not read in titles when using Android

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, mobile-web

On a mobile I do not get math symbolic  notation in title or comments. ( Main text ok ) Is there a fix applicable to Androids ?

Comment: It is on mobile web or when using Android App? See: [The math symbols cannot be correctly displayed in titles and comments (in Stack Exchange Android App)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22465) or [MathJax borks in titles in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221927).

Comment: There are no fixes to the android app. They have stopped developing it.

Comment: https://github.com/mksmbrtsh/jlatexmath-android